# Select a conversion in AppleScript using subject

Tags: applescript

I was looking in AppleScript's Mail dictionary and on the Internet but can't find anywhere how I can achieve the following:

In Mail app, when you click on conversation, preview pane displays all related mails. How can I achieve the same using AppleScript, i.e. get all related mails and store them in a list for later processing.

Context wise, I will be running this script as a rule (in conjunction with MAO) so that I can archive inbox and sent messages at the same time.

I know it is possible to iterate manually, one-by-one, but from what I know performance is really poor in that scenario.

Comment: It would be better for you to launch Script Editor and examine the AppleScript library for Mail there.  There are plenty of Mail scripts here and on other forums to get you started.

Comment: Library. Are you referring to dictionary or "Mail Rule Action.scptd"?

Comment: From Script Editor, choose Window --> Library.  From there, you can see all the AppleScript Libraries that are pre-installed.  By clicking the PLUS button, and selecting other Applications on your system, you can install other Libraries.  You can find more example scripts at [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net)

Comment: I actually did that which is referred to in my question as "dictionary" but thanks for the link

Comment: Right, sorry, I misunderstood.  Too much scanning and not enough actual reading.  There are a lot of challenges with scripting Mail these days, so be patient, and do not be surprised at the level of difficulty you encounter.  I have had to do a number of work-arounds over the years with my Mail scripts every time OS X is upgraded.  Ugh.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mail dictionary, unfortunately, there is nothing about conversation or threads. It seems that Mail just groups emails based on subject, but I am not 100% sure.

If confirmed by subject, you can get all emails of same subject in sent mailbox, inbox or any other local folder using bellow script :

```
set myTitle to "subject you're looking for"
tell application "Mail"
set myEmails to {}
set MailSent to {every message of sent mailbox whose subject contains myTitle}
set Mailreceived to {every message of inbox whose subject contains myTitle}
set BoxList to name of every mailbox
repeat with aBox in BoxList
    set end of myEmails to {every message of mailbox aBox whose subject contains myTitle}
end repeat
end tell
```

You get 3 lists MailSent, MailReceived and myEmails (folders on your mac)
I tested in my own mailboxes and I've been able to find conversations, but, still, it does not means it will always be correct 100%.

Comment: Seems like there is no way to do it natively so workaround it will be then